# Change Configurable Swatches Layout for some product

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches

I'd like to change configurable Swatches layout for a specific product.

I set the Custom Layout Update field on the admin panel:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
<reference name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches-new.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

But it's doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have put this code on ***Magento backend,then there are no need to specify handler***.

Just add this:

```
<reference name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches-new.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: ty, It's working like a charm

Comment: you are welcome..